# Vector drawables on pre-lollipop devices not working

Tags: android, android-support-library, xml-namespaces, android-vectordrawable

**REFERENCE**: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Using this official android developer's blog,I have coded for vector drawables for my app.
Code is working fine with lollipop devices,but not with pre-lolipop devices.

I have the following **dependencies** in my gradle -

```
com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0
```

My gradle version is 2.0.0-beta5, so as per the blog I added

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+ 
    android {  
       defaultConfig {  
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
        }  
     }
```

When I use `android:src` for ImageView,it works with lollipop devices. But app crashes for pre-lolipop devices with **android.view.InflateException**.
and as per the blog I am trying to use `app:srcCompat` for ImageView,I am getting a compile time error - **unexpected namespace prefix app**, though I have specified namespace app as `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in my layout.

Comment: Could you try to update to 23.2.1? Have you tried to remove the dependency for support-vector-drawable? https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/R2tonuM2Yzx

Comment: @Christopher, thanks for your reply. I tried 23.2.1 and even removing support-vector-drawable but no use. I am not getting any clue why I am unable to use app:srcCompat..

Comment: Hmm, curious. Another try: could you use android gradle plugin 2.0.0-beta6?

Comment: ohh god, thanks man @Christopher, updating to beta6 solved the problem :) Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Khristopher,Could you please tell the reason why it wan not working with the previous version.Although It solved the problem,but still did not get the reason why that was happening.You can provide the essential information in answer.

Answer (score 0):

use android gradle plugin 2.0.0-beta6 as mentioned above